# Adding a custom image header over a webpart in a horizintal webpart zone

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have a webpart zone that has three webparts horizontal to each other.
I would like to add an image ( custom header ) over the last of the three webparts. How do I do that?

When webparts are by default vertical, you can just add a content web part over it and that's it. But how do you do that in a webpart zone that has the webparts horizontal?

Using SP 2010.

Comment: Hi @Mike, Could you please share an image for the current  web parts horizontal.

Comment: Hey M.Qassas I cannot at the moment. They are just three webparts in a row but changed to show horizontal in a zone. The last of the three is a webpart calling a list. I'd like to add title over the latter with an image of a a customized title with a particular font and look. BTW it;s SP 2010.

Comment: @MikeRooker I feel that you need to add some more information about the webpart. Adding an image into web part is not difficult irrespective they aligned horizontally or vertically.

Comment: Yes thank you. :)  I realized the solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may need the answer it was one of the more obvious ones I over thought and over-looked.

Rather than changing the zone to display horizontally, you're better off inserting a table. Select how many columns ( in this case 3 ) and add a Web part into each column. In fact you can stack them ( have more than one web part in each column ) if you keep the default vertical placement of web parts.
So in column three I used a Content Web Editor, added the image and right under that I inserted another web part, this time a Custom Query one.